# AArch64 ESR Trapped WFI or WFE instruction execution

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm64, bare-metal

I am confused by the following entry in the ARM documentation for ESR_EL1:

EC, bits [31:26]
0b000001 Trapped WFI or WFE instruction execution.

What does it really mean that WFI or WFE were trapped? What is the meaning if this happens under Linux? Could this produce a kernel crash?

Answer (score 2):

It means that `SCTLR_EL1.nTWI` (bit 16) or `SCTLR_EL1.nTWE` (bit 18) were set to `0`, and something running at EL0 executed a `WFI` or `WFE` instruction.

Linux AArch64 userspace was apparently allowed to execute `WFI`/`WFE` until [this patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-arm-kernel/patch/20180807093326.5090-1-marc.zyngier@arm.com/), which installed an exception handler in the kernel that would skip the instructions, effectively turning them into `NOP`s.